# Cannot install Visual Studio 2017 Tools in a Docker container

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docker, msbuild

I'm attempting to create a Docker image with Visual Studio Code Analysis, which is part of the Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools.  The following Dockerfile works, and the tools are installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools`:

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing below.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

# Install VS Build Tools
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

ENTRYPOINT powershell
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

So far, so good.  However, I actually need to base the image off `microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk-windowsservercore-ltsc2016` since this will eventually become part of the TeamCity build agent image, and that's the image *that* is based on.  So, I change my FROM line to:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
```

When I build this, the image builds and I go no errors.  It appears to be working and takes around the same amount of time.  However, the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Team Tools\` is missing.  Perhaps it's some issue with 4.7.2, so I tried `microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1-sdk-windowsservercore-ltsc2016`.  Same error.  I also tried `microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk-windowsservercore-1803` also with no luck.  I also tried using Chocolatey to install the VS Build Tools but it's the exact same behavior.

What in the world would be so special about this `microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1` image where it's the only image that VS Build Tools will install on?  I couldn't find a Dockerfile for it, so I can't really tell what it's based on (They just say "Windows Server Core" which isn't helpful) or if this image installs or does anything special.

Has anyone gotten VS Build Tools to work in a container based on anything but `microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that appears to work.  It's more of a workaround until Microsoft fixes whatever bug that causes the VS Build Tools installer to not work on certain Windows images.

You can create a multistage build, and then copy over both the `Team Tools` folder plus the necessary `.targets` file.  If you install other things besides Static Code Analysis, you might need to find what target file(s) you'll need to copy as well.

Example:

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1 as vsbuild

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing below.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

# Install Static Analysis Tools
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

FROM jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2018.1.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

COPY --from=vsbuild ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/Team Tools", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/Team Tools"]
COPY --from=vsbuild ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/CodeAnalysis", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/CodeAnalysis"]
```

Comment: That may work for some workloads, but many workloads install files outside of the install root or make other machine configuration changes like registry changes that you cannot simply copy over. The bug was identified and fixed before RS5 shipped, but we have no plans to fix older releases given our servicing lifecycle. 15.9 is required (which contains the fix) for RS5 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 requires Windows Server 2019 or Windows 10 "RS5". See https://aka.ms/setup/containers/servercore1809.